# What is the name if this glittery fly seen in Pittsburgh?

Tags: entomology, species-identification

I have photographed the following fly which is iridescent green in Pittsburgh, PA.
I guess it was about 0.5-1.5cm long.

Can you help me to identify it?

[image]

Comment: And here it is: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Lucilia-sericata.jpg

Comment: Gorgeous photo!

Comment: Thank you for making your photo available as Creative Commons. I use many CC-licensed photo in my classes. Perhaps I will one day use yours.

Comment: @moose Iridescent is probably the word you are looking for.

Comment: It's a blowfly. They sometimes ruin my compost heaps (the larvae).

Comment: This is the most annoying fly from all the commonly found flies!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like a green bottle fly.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_bottle_fly

Might be a Common Green bottle fly.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_green_bottle_fly